# Formating a range of cells (the range of cells is based on a formula)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

The column A has dates. Starting from A4.
So lets say that
A4 has "September 4, 2023"
A5 has "September 5, 2023"
A6 has "September 6, 2023"
A7 has "September 7, 2023"
And so on....

B1 has the start date, and B2 has the end date for a specific person's name. The name is in B3.

I want the range of cells highlighted in the B column based on start date and end date.

Conditional formating maybe?

Comment: Yes, conditional formatting. Are you on google-sheet or excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula in custom CF rule.

```
=INDEX(((A4:A>=$B$1)*(A4:A<=$B$2)))
```

[image]